# Помогите с SELECT COUNT(), не хочет работать

Tags: php, sql, pdo

Добрый день, есть постраничное разбитие (например по 20 на страницу). Пытаюсь перейти на PDO и не выходит, помогите плс кто в теме.

Было (РАБОТАЕТ)

```
$i = 1;
if(!$page){
$p = 0;} else {$p = (($page - 1) * 20);}

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM table LIMIT $p,20");
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($sql)){

//тут данные выводимые в кол 20 ед.

$i++; }
```

Вывод кнопок страниц

```
$count = mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM table");

$countr = mysql_fetch_row($count);
$total_rows = ($countr[0]);
$n = ($total_rows / 20);
$n = ceil($n);

if ($n > 1){

    if (!$page) {
    echo '<a href="file" class="next_active">1</a>';
    }
    else {
    echo '<a href="file">1</a>';
    }



for ($i = 2; $i <= $n; $i++){

    if ($i == $page) {
    echo '<a href="file/'.$i.'" class="next_active">'.$i.'</a>';
    }
    else {
    echo '<a href="file/'.$i.'">'.$i.'</a>';
    }
}
}
```

Стало (НЕ РАБОТАЕТ) Выводит кнопки ,при переходе добавляет слеш и цифру сраницы, вывод данных остается тем же(тоесть те данные которые были на первой странице)

```
$i = 1;
if(!$page){
$p = 0;} else {$p = (($page - 1) * 20);}    
    $sqlmsc = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM table LIMIT $p,20");
    while ($row = $sqlmsc->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){

//тут данные выводимые в кол 20 ед.
 $i++; }
```

Вывод кнопок страниц

```
    $count = $conn->query("SELECT COUNT(id) FROM table");
    $countr = $count->fetch(PDO::FETCH_NUM);

$total_rows = ($countr[0]);
$n = ($total_rows / 20);
$n = ceil($n);

if ($n > 1){

    if (!$page) {
    echo '<a href="file" class="next_active">1</a>';
    }
    else {
    echo '<a href="file">1</a>';
    }



for ($i = 2; $i <= $n; $i++){

    if ($i == $page) {
    echo '<a href="file/'.$i.'" class="next_active">'.$i.'</a>';
    }
    else {
    echo '<a href="file/'.$i.'">'.$i.'</a>';
    }
}

}
```

штакес `RewriteRule ^file/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /file.php?table=$1&page=$2 [L]`

Comment: Вопрос решен! Помогли в другом месте. Кому интересно решение:
`if(isset($_GET['page'])){$page = $_GET['page'];}
if ($page AND !preg_match("|^[\d]+$|", $page)) { Header ("Location: /"); }`

Comment: за `preg_match` леща советнику отвешайте

Comment: а чего? так работает же

Comment: потому что [`is_int()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.is-int.php) для этих целей есть

Comment: Будем пробовать, спасибо за подсказку

Comment: Не уверен, но, по-моему в вопросе нужно убрать код "было" - он не нужен для ответа на вопрос, но при этом занимает очень много места.

Answer (score 0):

При создании коннекта в базе, там где у Вас должно быть:

```
$conn = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password)
```

добавляете еще одну переменную в конец:

```
$options = [ PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false ];
$conn = new PDO($dsn, $username, $password, $options);
```

Если уже есть $options, то просто добавляете туда указанный параметр.
Если этого не указать, то PDO будет эмулировать подготовленные запросы и, по сути, собирать их сам (вместо того чтобы оставить это черное дело для драйвера самой базы данных). Всё бы ничего, но побочным эффектом эмуляции является невозможность подставить числа в конструкцию LIMIT.

Далее, для чего вообще Вам PDO? Тут вспоминается анекдот про бензопилу (а она еще и включается?). Обязательно произведите замену:

```
// старое
$sqlmsc = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM table LIMIT $p,20");
// новое
$stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM table LIMIT ?,20");
$sqlmsc = $stmt->execute([$p]);
```

Теперь Вам не страшны sql-инъекции (по крайней мере в этом месте).

P.S. Вообще, действительно, там где Вам посоветовали воспользоваться preg_match для обработки параметра - как минимум не спрашивайте там больше. А еще лучше - научите и того человека пользоваться PDO.

P.P.S. В принципе всегда в запросах Вы должны использовать подстановку параметров. При этом, если это запрос типа SELECT и результат будет использован исключительно для вывода на форме - вообще никогда никаких проверок/валидаций/исправлений не нужно делать. Это лишь усложняет и загромождает код, а также кушает ресурсы сервера.